# Why does BLE API not discover my phone? it is selective in discovering devices

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Why do BLE android APIs not discover my phone. I have tried all type of codes. But it is not discovering my phone. But discovers other devices.
My manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

This is the only runtime permission->
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 123);
        }
```

DO I have to enable GPS and Network also? how to do that?

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted, yay! Start the Bluetooth device scan.
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                } else {
                    // Alert the user that this application requires the location permission to perform the scan.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually it requires Run time permissions.Did you give any run time permissions to scan your Bluetooth

Comment: I have given only 1 run-time permission as stated in update description.

Comment: As of now just go to settings-Apps-your Application-enable the location permissions and run the application and check whether it detect the BLE or not

Comment: where is settings,are you talking about android studio settings, there is no Apps folder under that

Comment: noo...just enable the permissions in your phone for your application

Comment: I have enabled bluetooth and gps

Comment: location permission is already there